# setInterval is not updating my clock time. The time displays and refreshes when I manually refresh the page

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a setInterval for each 1000 milliseconds, but the clock will not refresh. I have to refresh the page for the clock to display the correct time.

```
function InitClock() {
    setInterval(function () {
        var mytime = getDateTime();
        console.log(mytime);
        document.getElementById("divClock").innerHTML = mytime;
    }, 1000);
}
```

I'm not quite sure what is going on.

Comment: You'll need to show the code for `getDateTime()`.

Comment: Can you show where you use `InitClock()`?

Comment: Also, do you get any errors in console?

Answer (score 1):

Check the console if your function `getDateTime();` isn't throwing some sort of an error. Also check you actually call the function `InitClock();` somewhere... See the code below which should work using the `new Date();` object.

```html
<html>

<script>
function InitClock() {
    setInterval(function () {
        var mytime = new Date();
        console.log(mytime);
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = mytime;
    }, 1000);
}

InitClock();
</script>

<body>
    <div id="date"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

*getDateTime* is not a built-in Javascript function. You need to instantiate a Javascript Date object, and use its methods to get date information. You can find more info on the Date object on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), one of the best resources for Javascript. You could do the following:

```
function InitClock() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var date = new Date(),
        mytime = date.getTime();
        console.log(mytime);
        document.getElementById("divClock").innerHTML = mytime;
    }, 1000);
}
```

I would optimize it a little bit by caching the DOM element for the clock before running the setInterval:

```
function InitClock() {
        var clockEl = document.getElementById("divClock");

        setInterval(function() {
            var date = new Date(),
            mytime = date.getTime();
            console.log(mytime);
            clockEl.innerHTML = mytime;
        }, 1000);
    }
```